# Mouse events duplicated with Tk menu commands, not accelerator keys

Tags: menu, tcl, mouseevent, tk-toolkit

This question pertains to Tcl/Tk 8.5.9 (via a starkit runtime) and 8.6 (via TkCon 2.7) on 64-bit Win7, and brings me back to the first Tk scripts I ever wrote.  With the following:

```
menu .menubar
. config -menu .menubar
menu .menubar.file -tearoff 0
.menubar add cascade -label "File" -menu .menubar.file -underline 0
.menubar.file add command -label "Test" -command {puts "Test"}
```

When invoking the "Test" menu command graphically, I get "Test" on stdout twice, as if the button-release event is duplicated.  With a keyboard accelerator assigned to this menu command, the key command works as expected (i.e. executing the command only once).

The widget configure options look as follows:

```
% .menubar.file configure
{-activebackground activeBackground Foreground SystemHighlight SystemHighlight} {-activeborderwidth activeBorderWidth BorderWidth 0 1} {-activeforeground activeForeground Background SystemHighlightText SystemHighlightText} {-background background Background SystemMenu SystemMenu} {-bd -borderwidth} {-bg -background} {-borderwidth borderWidth BorderWidth 0 1} {-cursor cursor Cursor arrow arrow} {-disabledforeground disabledForeground DisabledForeground SystemDisabledText SystemDisabledText} {-fg -foreground} {-font font Font TkMenuFont {{Segoe UI} 9}} {-foreground foreground Foreground SystemMenuText SystemMenuText} {-postcommand postCommand Command {} {}} {-relief relief Relief flat flat} {-selectcolor selectColor Background SystemMenuText SystemMenuText} {-takefocus takeFocus TakeFocus 0 0} {-tearoff tearOff TearOff 1 0} {-tearoffcommand tearOffCommand TearOffCommand {} {}} {-title title Title {} {}} {-type type Type normal normal}

% .menubar.file entryconfigure 0
{-activebackground {} {} {} {}} {-activeforeground {} {} {} {}} {-accelerator {} {} {} {}} {-background {} {} {} {}} {-bitmap {} {} {} {}} {-columnbreak {} {} 0 0} {-command {} {} {} {puts "Test"}} {-compound compound Compound none none} {-font {} {} {} {}} {-foreground {} {} {} {}} {-hidemargin {} {} 0 0} {-image {} {} {} {}} {-label {} {} {} Test} {-state {} {} normal normal} {-underline {} {} -1 -1}
```

This problem does not occur with 8.5 on a Mac.

I see a lot of material alluding to something like this with Python and Tkinter, though I'm not using Python.  I also wondered if this could relate to the mouse on my Win box, though swapping the same mouse between this machine and the Mac does not alter the behavior above.

Has anyone seen this before?

---

Update: By chance, I happened to notice that when I allow the menu to be torn off, and then when I invoke the tearoff, there are actually two File menu windows that are created.  When I separate these (i.e. drag them so they are not overlapping each other), clicking each Test menu entry individually causes the command to be invoked only once.  So somehow I've created duplicate menus. (This is 8.6.4/8.6.4 from TkCon 2.7.)

Comment: Can't duplicate w/8.6.6 on win7-64.

Comment: Can't either with Tcl 8.6.4, Tk 8.6.4, win7.

Comment: If the question is that last one, no, I've never seen this before.

Comment: The duplicated, overlapping menus would cause the problem.   Unfortunately, Tk leaks the mouse events through to the lower window.   I already have a bug report open for this problem.

Comment: Updated the [ticket](http://core.tcl.tk/tk/tktview/131adc6b77dc65d55edc0d108566226079976cb7) with the reference to this question.